# Sending keys using Selenium and headless Chrome

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

Using [headless chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) and selenium I can succesfully send keys to websites on my Mac. When I port the same code to my Linux machine it crashes however. The offending line is the following one:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="username"]').send_keys(username)
```

And I get the following error message:

```
"an X display is required for keycode conversions, consider using Xvfb"
```

Why is this not working on Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in chromedriver that is detailed [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1772#c28).

According to the new lead for chrome driver

> The issue is in ChromeDriver. As its name implies, the sendKey command sends simulated key strokes to Chrome, and ChromeDriver is responsible for converting the input text string into corresponding keystrokes to send to Chrome. On Linux, ChromeDriver uses X display to do the conversion, and fails when no X display is available.

It has been fixed recently and will be released in v 2.31. Unfortunately the chromium team does not make nightly builds publicly available and there is no official release date yet.

In the meantime you can [build your own chromedriver](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux_build_instructions.md) or download a prebuilt binary from a third party... Both a dockerfile and a working binary may be found at [this github](https://github.com/jalexvig/build_chromium_docker).